# Sharepoint-Mapped Network Drive can create new folders but not rename

Tags: sharepoint

I was able to map my sharepoint drive on my local computer (Note: this was not using the sync option on sharepoint, as I do not have access to do so). I am able to create new folders, however I am unable to rename it. When I try to rename the folder, I get the following message, regardless of how many characters I put:

[image: Folder Creation]

I can change the file name from the sharepoint web portal, but not on my mapped network drive.
I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the same problem, but [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/4ea9b978-4fd8-416b-a4e1-a7b989380973/unable-to-rename-folders-and-files-on-sharepoint-mapped-drive?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) guy got the same error message when he mapped the drive using a `/` at the end of the URL.

(i.e. he solved remapping: `https://hostname.domain.com/Shared Documents`

instead of: `https://hostname.domain.com/Shared Documents/` )